# Как реализовать справку о сайте

Tags: javascript

Когда-то на хабре видел статью о js библиотеке, которой можно легко сделать инструкцию по сайту. То есть зашли на сайт, нажали "ознакомиться" и нам показывает пошаговую инструкцию, что к чему.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Есть ряд библиотек для этого:

- [Website tour](http://tympanus.net/codrops/2010/12/21/website-tour/) - [Демо](http://tympanus.net/Development/WebsiteTour/)
- [jQuery Tour](http://codecanyon.net/item/jquery-tour-the-flexible-tour-plugin/1052564) - [Демо](http://revaxarts-themes.com/?t=tour)
- [Joyride](http://www.zurb.com/playground/jquery-joyride-feature-tour-plugin)
- [Crumble](http://tommoor.github.com/crumble/)
- [Intro.js](https://github.com/usablica/intro.js) - [Демо](http://usablica.github.io/intro.js/)
- [myTips.co](http://mytips.co)

Comment: спасибо, то что нужно